# No Relationship class found in neo4jphp when using neo4jphp.phar

Tags: neo4j

When running neo4jphp/neo4jphp.phar on a local machine, seems that Noe4j - 1.9.RC2 works correctly. Also, the web interface is available.

When runnning the command (below)

```
$arthurOutgoingRelationships = $arthur->getRelationships(array(),     Relationship::DirectionOut);
```

, I am having

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Relationship' not found in /var/www/index.php
```

in the Apache error log. I downloaded the latest available version of neo4jphp as well as registered the autoloader:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
  $libPath = '/var/www/neo4jphp/lib/';
  $classFile = str_replace('\\',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$className).'.php';
  $classPath = $libPath.$classFile;
  if (file_exists($classPath)) {
     require($classPath);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by downloading the library from [GitHub](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp), copy the Everyman folder with its subfolders in your root directory and use what you need. In example

```
    require("phar://neo4jphp.phar");
    use Everyman\Neo4j\Relationship;
```